# Show that the Poincare disk is complete metric space with respect to the hyperbolic metric.

Tags: complex-analysis, metric-spaces, hyperbolic-geometry, complete-spaces

I want to show that the unit disk equipped with the hyperbolic metric is a complete metric space.

The metric is defined as: 
$d_{P}(w,z)=inf\{l_{h}(\gamma): \gamma$ is a partial smooth curve in $\mathbb{D}$ with initial point at z and ending point w$\}.$

I want to show that every Cauchy sequence is convergent but I find it difficult.

I also know that the hyperbolic metric is equivalent to the Euclidean metric but I do not think that this is useful since completeness is not a topological property.

Any answer or discussion on that would be really useful.

Comment: How is the hyperbolic metric defined? While completeness might not be preserved with equivalent metrics, it might be preserved here.

Comment: @Jakobian Sadly it will not: whatever the definition of hyperbolic metric could be, the open disk endowed with the euclidean metric is not complete!

Comment: @Didier the closed disk is, which is most likely what we're talking about here anyway

Comment: @Jakobian I don't think so. OP is referring to the [Poincaré disk](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poincar%C3%A9_disk_model) in the title, which is the open disk endowed with a particular (Riemannian) metric, making it into a complete metric space (with negative curvature). It is topologically equivalent to the euclidean metric though. However, I agree with you that OP should explicitly write down their definition of hyperbolic metric since it can be done in very (all equivalent) different ways and the answer will highly depend on this choice

Comment: You're right, if we were talking about the closed disk then the question would be trivial anyway since both spaces would just be compact. How OP talked about completeness of unit disk with Euclidean metric confused me a little

Comment: The disk we are talking about is the open unit disk and the metric is defined as $d_{P}(w,z)=inf\{l_{h}(\gamma): \gamma$ is a partial smooth curve in $\mathbb{D}$ with initial point at z and ending point w$\}$.

Comment: @GiorgosKosmas You did not define what is the hyperbolic length $l_h(\gamma)$ of a path $\gamma$. You should state all these things in the question to make it self-contained

Comment: It would also help to know if _completeness_ means Cauchy completeness (as suggested by wording) or geodesic completeness (as suggested by context). The properties are logically equivalent, but approaches may differ depending on the aims.

Comment: show that if you fix $z$ then $d_P(z,w) \to \infty$ if $|w| \to 1$ which immediately gives you that any Cauchy sequence is included in some $|z| \le r <1$ which is compact Euclidean and the metrics are equivalent there (so an Euclidean convergent/Cauchy sequence is Hyperbolic convergent/Cauchy and viceversa)  etc

Comment: @Conrad: that looks like an answer